# Use maven to generate ODL code Framework in windows

Tags: opendaylight

When I use this command :

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=org.opendaylight.controller -DarchetypeArtifactId=opendaylight-startup-archetype -DarchetypeRepository=http://nexus.opendaylight.org/content/repositories/public/ -DarchetypeCatalog=remote -DarchetypeVersion=1.3.1-Carbon
```

Then result is

```
Error: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:3.0.1:generate (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: The desired archetype does not exist (org.opendaylight.controller:opendaylight-startup-archetype:1.3.1-Carbon)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OpenDaylight project doesn't use Maven Central (yet) to publish artifacts, so you need to tell Maven where the ODL repositories are. For that you need your `$HOME/.m2/settings.xml` file set up as described in the developer documentation [here](https://docs.opendaylight.org/en/stable-fluorine/developer-guide/developing-apps-on-the-opendaylight-controller.html?highlight=settings.xml#pre-requisites). I recommend you use the latest archetype version (1.6.0), since if you run into issues that's the most likely you will be able to get support with.

Comment: Please accept the answer as the solution if was complete enough to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow [the official documentation on docs.opendaylight.org](https://docs.opendaylight.org/en/stable-oxygen/developer-guide/developing-apps-on-the-opendaylight-controller.html).

The community on the [archetypes-dev mailing list](https://lists.opendaylight.org/mailman/listinfo/archetypes-dev) may also be able to help.